# Subdomains and related links on a website

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, permalinks, subdomain

I'm working on the complete structure of a web page, and I'm using directories to the url of the site the user can understand the site map, with categories and subcategories. for example. My homepage is www.mantarrayamx.com.

The page I am trying to load is www.mantarrayamx.com/services/seo, but for seo I am using the subdomain seo.mantarrayamx.com to access this directory directly.

I'm using third-party code, for example "font awesome". Unfortunately, the web page loading failed because the links are relative. I try entering in the CSS and JS including of third-party code and yet it still loads with errors. You can see the difference between loading by subdomain and loading by sub-directory here:

- mantarrayamx.com/servicios/posicionamientoweb/
- posicionamientoweb.mantarrayamx.com/

**The question is:**
What is the best way to use and manage subdomains and links (../img/)?

For example: How do you do google in your applications:

- drive.google.com
- mail.google.com

If I have to modify the `.htaccess` file, please give me an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I get your question, you are accessing a subdirectory of your server by using a subdomain. On this subdomain, your data is in the root-directory. I guess you are using absolute links in your app, like:

- /service/type/(index.php) or
- /about/me/(index.php)

First of all: If you just want to have this for seo-friendlieness and beautiful links, you should definitely use *mod_rewrite* or the appropriate *nginx-config*. This saves you from having real subdirectories - you just "fake" them. The following code rewrites all requested URLS to `index.php?r=theenteredurl`. In PHP (or, if you want, any other processing language of your choice) you can sanitize the URL, analyse it and then server the correct content.

**mod_rewrite:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?r=$1 [L]
```

**Nginx:**

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?r=$request_uri;
}
```

The good thing about this solution is, that the only file that really gets processed is your `index.php` and you therefor have your app/website tidy and on one place. But be aware: HTML, CSS and JS relative links do **NOT** work as you might expect with this solution, since they do not see what PHP processes, but only what is in the address-bar of your browser. All relative links are relative to the fake subdirectory. To solve this, you can define a base-url in your HTML-file. All other files loaded in this HTML file will be relative to this url.

If I got you wrong and you really *want* to have real sub-directories on the one domain and no subdirectories on the other, then you could use the HTML base-tag to define a different base-URL depending on whether you are on the main domain or the subdomain. To find out the latter, try the [PHP super-global $_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/reserved.variables.server.php). Please note, that HTML cannot access something that is out of the public scope - if your ressources are in a higher subdirectory that is not publicly accessable on this subdomain, you have no chance of loading it in HTML files.